# Problem with connect by Sequelize when I connect to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I use the `mssql` package and connect to database like this:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'xxxxxx',
    server: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    database: 'zorgo',
    options : {
        enableArithAbort: false,
        cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            minVersion: 'TLSv1'
        }
    }
};
```

Now I want to try 'sequelize' library and try to connect

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize('zorgo', 'sa', 'xxxxxx', {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: false,
        cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
            minVersion: 'TLSv1'
        }
    }
});
```

But I get an error

> Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1433 - 584:error:1425F102:SSL routines:ssl_choose_client_version:unsupported protocol

Please help me resolve this problem

Comment: Are you making both connections from the same client machine/container/guest to the same SQL Server instance? If they're different clients they may have different mssql versions, different OpenSSL versions or different settings in their /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf files.

Comment: I am making connection at the same SQL Server from the same app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question

```
    const sequelize = new Sequelize('zorgo', 'sa', 'xxxxxx', {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    dialectOptions: {
        options: {
            enableArithAbort: false,
            cryptoCredentialsDetails: {
                minVersion: 'TLSv1'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And works well...